# Intel HD Graphics 3000 can't be installed in Asus K43SV(Intel Core i3-2310m@2,1 GHz)

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I'd been trying to install Intel HD Graphics 3000 for my notebook with differences version, but nothing. I've gotten massage from system "Your computer doesn't meet the minimum requirement for installing this software" So, i need help from this forum to solve my problem. Spesifications of my notebook are listed below:
Asus K43SV
Intel(TM) Core(R) i3-2310m@2,1 GHz, 
NVidia geforce GT 540M, Cuda, 2 GB
RAM 2 GB

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the spec sheet, http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K43SV/specifications/, it does not appear that you can install the intel drivers because the graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M; not a Intel HD integrated graphics card. You should install the NVIDIA drivers instead.

Comment: This's sad.. I waiting for about 10 yeas til now still no one from asus care about this.. asus is killing the comunity for sake of profit... I still use my K43SV daily basis, but the newer battery only could power it for 1,5 hours, which is insanely not practical, but the problem I still like this laptop, A LOT. so yeah.. I just try to stick with it, and the replacement battery always fail when reach 6 months. There're no original battery anymore that's sold freely. Even asus doesn't handle the request of new original battery anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://downloadcenter.intel.com

Click "Update Drivers" on the left.

See what it offers.